# Converting arabic numbers into chinese financial numbers

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to create a function in functional programming, which recieves a normal Int value and translates it to financial chinese numbers and returns a String, for exaple: 301 = 三百零一. To begin, I have two maps, one with every digit from 0 to 9, and the other one with the exponentials, from 10, to 1000000.

`val digits: Map[Int, String] = Map(0 -> "〇", 1 -> "壹", 2 -> "貳", 3 -> "參", 4 -> "肆", 5 -> "伍", 6 -> "陸", 7 -> "柒", 8 -> "捌", 9 -> "玖");`

`val exponent: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "", 10 -> "拾", 100 -> "佰", 1000 -> "仟", 10000 -> "萬", 100000 -> "億", 1000000 -> "兆");`

For the ones who don´t know, here goes a little explanation about how chinese numbers work. If you already know, don´t bother in reading this paragraph. In the chinese numbers, when you want to write a large number, for example 5000, you write the 5 and the 1000 symbols (伍仟) to intimate that you are multiplying 5 * 1000. If you have 539, it´s 5*100 + 3*10 + 9. This would be 伍佰參拾玖. Lastly, if the number has 0´s between multiplications, it doesn´t matter how many they are, you write only one 0 between the other characters. For example: 501 = 5*100 + 1. This is 伍佰〇壹. One last example for calrification: 50103 = 5*10000 + 1*100 + 3. This is 伍萬〇壹佰〇參.

So what I could do, is the following:

```
def format(unit: Int): String = {
val l = unit.toString.map(_.asDigit).toList
if(l.isEmpty) ""
else if(l.tail.isEmpty) digits(l.head)
else digits(l.head) + format(l.tail.mkString.toInt)
}
```

This translates the characters one by one. For example:

```
format(135) "壹參伍"
```

And I don´t know how to continue.

Comment: I believe "億" should be `10^8` and "兆" `10^12`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly you can do something like this:

```
def toChineseFinancial(number: Int): String = {
  val digits = number.toString.iterator.map(_.asDigit).toList
  val length = digits.length
  val exponents = List.tabulate(length)(n => math.pow(10, n).toInt)
  
  val (sb, _) =
    digits
      .iterator
      .zip(exponents.reverseIterator)
      .foldLeft(new collection.mutable.StringBuilder(length * 2) -> false) {
        case ((sb, flag), (digit, exp)) =>
          if (digit == 0) sb -> true
          else if (flag) sb.append("〇").append(digitsMap(digit)).append(exponentsMap(exp)) -> false
          else sb.append(digitsMap(digit)).append(exponentsMap(exp)) -> false
      }
  
  sb.result()
}
```

You can see it running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/CRYSNZ5iQCKmXoOIr0aDnw/6).

---

*Note: I used `mutable.StringBuilder` because building **Strings** is somewhat expensive, but if you want to avoid any kind of mutability you can easily replace it with a normal **String***.

Answer (score 1):

I would expand the `exponents` Map using a simple `case class` for its values to cover:

- numbers of magnitude 1, 10, 10^2, ..., 10^12
- 10's, 100's and 1000's of "萬" (10^4), "億" (10^8) and "兆" (10^12)

as shown below:

```
case class CNU(unit: String, factor: Int)

val exponents: Map[Long, CNU] = Map(
  1L -> CNU("", 1),
  10L -> CNU("拾", 1),
  100L -> CNU("佰", 1),
  1000L -> CNU("仟", 1),
  10000L ->CNU("萬", 1),
  100000L -> CNU("萬", 10),
  1000000L -> CNU("萬", 100),
  10000000L -> CNU("萬", 1000),
  100000000L -> CNU("億", 1),
  1000000000L -> CNU("億", 10),
  10000000000L -> CNU("億", 100),
  100000000000L -> CNU("億", 1000),
  1000000000000L -> CNU("兆", 1),
  10000000000000L -> CNU("兆", 10),
  100000000000000L -> CNU("兆", 100),
  1000000000000000L -> CNU("兆", 1000)
)
```

Creating the method:

```
val digits: Map[Int, String] = Map(
  0 -> "〇", 1 -> "壹", 2 -> "貳", 3 -> "參", 4 -> "肆",
  5 -> "伍", 6 -> "陸", 7 -> "柒", 8 -> "捌", 9 -> "玖"
)

def toChineseNumber(num: Long): String = {
  val s = num.toString
  val ds = s.map(_.asDigit).zip(s.length-1 to 0 by -1)

  ds.foldRight(List.empty[String], 0){ case ((d, i), (accList, dPrev)) =>
      val cnu = exponents(math.pow(10, i).toLong)

      val digit =
        if (d == 0) {
          if (dPrev != 0 || num == 0) digits(d) else ""
        }
        else
          digits(d)

      val unit =
        if (d == 0)
          "" 
        else {
          if (cnu.factor == 1) cnu.unit else exponents(cnu.factor).unit
        }

      ((digit + unit) :: accList, d)
    }.
    _1.mkString
}
```

Note that method `foldRight` is used to traverse and process the input number from right to left and `dPrev` in the tuple-accumulator is for carrying digits across iterations for handling repetitive 0's.

Testing it:

```
toChineseNumber(50)
// res1: String = 伍拾

toChineseNumber(30001)
// res2: String = 參萬〇壹

toChineseNumber(1023405)
// res3: String = 壹佰〇貳萬參仟肆佰〇伍

toChineseNumber(2233007788L)
// res4: String = 貳拾貳億參仟參佰〇柒仟柒佰捌拾捌
```